# how to find the difference between two dates in HH:MM:SS format in objective c?

Tags: objective-c

I think the heading itself says what i want to do?

Stil,let me clarify. I am right now working on an application where i have two dated in a format like :

> "YYYY:MM:DD HH:MM:SS"

Using which i need to calculate difference between the both dates in the format :

> HH:MM:SS

I searched in the wiki and also tried my luck but in vain.Can anybody help me out?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's the steps that I think you'll need to perform:

1. Parse both the dates into `NSDate` objects using an [`NSDateFormatter`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSDateFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html).
2. Calculate the difference between the two dates using

   ```
   NSTimeInterval ti = [laterDate timeIntervalSinceDate:earlierDate];
   ```
3. The `ti` variable above now contains the number of seconds between the two dates. You can reformat that into hours, seconds and minutes with:

   ```
   NSUInteger h, m, s;
   h = (ti / 3600);
   m = ((NSUInteger)(ti / 60)) % 60;
   s = ((NSUInteger) ti) % 60;
   NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu:%02lu:%02lu", h, m, s];
   ```

#### Disclaimer

It is late at night for me so the above calculations for hours, minutes and seconds may not be correct.