# Timer Count Down with UIDatePicker in iOS

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uidatepicker

In my app , i let user to set Count Down timer with `UIDatePicker's` `CountDownTimer`.

I have one `UILabel` to show count time When user choose time from CountDownTimer, i want to show coumt down that user chosen in CoutDownTimer like following pic.

[image]

So i retrieve count time that user chosen from `CountDownTimer` with following code

```
self.dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[self.dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"HH:mm:ss"];

self.sleepTimer = [NSTimer timerWithTimeInterval:1.00 target:self selector:@selector(timerFired:) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
```

When it reach 00:00 , i want to fire a event.

I don't know how to reduce every second count down.

Thanks you for your help.

Comment: You need `NSTimer`. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1449035/how-do-i-use-nstimer

Comment: yes i know , but i don't know how to reduce 1 every second

Comment: You need a variable to decrement every time the timer fires until it reaches 0.

Comment: how can i do it bro?Please with code

Comment: `datePicker.countDownDuration -= 1;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Save the `countDownDuration` property of your `UIDatePicker` (the value is given in seconds) in an instance variable called something like `secondsLeft`.

```
self.sleepTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.00 target:self selector:@selector(timerFired:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

That will call your method `timerFired:` every second. Subtract `secondsLeft` by 1. Update your `UILabel` with the time left (format your seconds into hh:mm:ss - [See this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4042958/how-to-find-the-difference-between-two-dates-in-hhmmss-format-in-objective-c/4043251#4043251) on formatting). Validate if there is time left on the count down and take the appropriate action if the count down is complete (`secondsLeft <= 0`).

Remember to clean up once the countdown is complete;

```
[self.sleepTimer invalidate];
self.sleepTimer = nil;
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do it by :

```
[NSTimer timerWithTimeInterval:1.00 target:self selector:@selector(decrementByOne:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

Comment: i don't know how to reduce 1 for NSDateFormatter.plz help.

Comment: I didn't talk for dateFormatter. I said make a counter that will be counted per second from starting. Then the above selector will call it per second and your counter will be decrementedByOne and display it.

Answer (score 0):

Take your date, save it into a property and take a look at NSDates

```
– dateByAddingTimeInterval:
```

So if you do

```
[self.date dateByAddingTimeInterval:-1];
```

you will decrement your date by 1 Second. 
After that, update you UI with the new calculated date.

Further you could package all the code in one function and execute this function by calling:

```
performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:
```